# Fatal error: while accessing SQL Server Tables

Tags: php, sql-server-2014-express

I am getting following fatal error while accessing data from SQL Server 2014 through PHP Script.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'test_table', database 'test_db', schema 'dbo'.
```

My PHP Script is

```
$server = 'KESAVATDL\SQLEXPRESS';    //KESAVATDL\SQLEXPRESS
$dbname = "acharya_db";
$usname="";
$passwd="";

try
{
    $con=new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server;Database=$dbname",$usname,$passwd);


    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    echo "Connected Successfully.";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
   echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM test";

foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row) {
   print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the PHP script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Users', database 'XXX', schema 'dbo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334041/the-select-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-users-database-xxx-schema)